# Can possible transform translateXY mixin function in sass

Tags: css, sass

Hello i am using mixin fuction for translateX and translateY and create only one function for both value X and Y that is possible or not please help Thanks in Adavance.

Example-1 is possible because only one value pass but another example is possilbe or not any other idea for pass two value at a time in only one function in SASS ?

Example-1

```css
@mixin translateX($value) {
    -webkit-transform: translateX($value);
    -moz-transform: translateX($value);
    -ms-transform: translateX($value);
    transform: translateX($value);
}
```

Example-2

```
@mixin translateXY($value1, $value2) {
    -webkit-transform: translateXY($value1, $value2);
    -moz-transform: translateXY($value1, $value2);
    -ms-transform: translateXY($value1, $value2);
    transform: translateXY($value1, $value2);
}
```

Comment: Its possible !! mixin is like a function in any language, you can pass how much parameters you want, and you can set a start value for it like this
`@mixin translateXY($value1, $value2: 30)` if you don't pass the second value it will assume 30 as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sass as below:

Set in `@include` the params of `translate`:`@include translateXY(30%,50%);`

And in `@mixin` **use  `translate` and not `translateXY`**

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bzn3axo/)

```
@mixin translateXY($value1, $value2) {
  .try{
    -webkit-transform: translate($value1, $value2);
    -moz-transform: translate($value1, $value2);
    -ms-transform: translate($value1, $value2);
    transform: translate($value1, $value2);
    }
}

@include translateXY(30%,50%);
```

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: Yeah this is working but this is only one particular class right

Comment: Yes .. if you want more classes add to `@mixim`

Comment: happy to help :)